# backbonejs frontend bound via an api to a nodejs backend

Tags: javascript, api, frontend, backend

Here's my concept:

```
  'Javascript Frontend in the Browser (eg. Backbonejs)'
            Handles most of the logic

                       |
                 'RESTful API'
                       |
                       V

     'API Backend (eg. nodejs, python, ruby)'
             Only handles raw data
```

And my question is: Is this a stable architecture? Doesn't it create more possible points of failure than a generic python/ruby/java web app? Also, is it a good idea to base the frontend on an API that could, one day, become publicly accessible?

Comment: It creates the same amount of failure points. Replace "javascript front end" with "browser"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've built multiple tools at work using this exact design. I haven't had any major issues at all. The most complex part was the use of web sockets to define an API that Backbone interacts with, but you can easily swap that with ajax for reduced complexity.

Comment: hey Malachor, thanks for your reply. Would you be able to give me a better of idea of the complexities behind building the API?

Comment: Sure thing. Setting up the actual socket API was easy. You just define your end points in your server code. Client side is a bit trickier. I needed an easy way to bind my Backbone collections and models to the socket. I ended up using this project [link](https://github.com/logicalparadox/backbone.iobind). I forget if I had to make changes to the code, but it was fairly easy to setup. 
For the data store, I use MongoDB. It has a JSON like way of formatting its data so I originally wanted to use the same structure on the client and DB. (cont.)

Comment: It wasn't the most elegant code, so I settled with writing some formatters that would prepare the data before sending it to the client. This was done with Mongo's static schema functions.

The really nice thing about that iobind library is how the socket urls will match your collection or model name. So if you had a collection called Tasks, the create event would have a socket endpoint at `socket.on('tasks:create', function(data){})`

Anyways, I hope that helps you out. It can be a pain working with Node.js and nested callbacks, especially when using MongoDB, but you get used to it :)